# how to generate path for customised icon image in wpf

Tags: wpf, path, icons

I am New to WPF. I have used path of images in my application.

It is like this:

```
<StreamGeometry x:Key="IconMinimize" >
    F1M1,1C1,1 11,1 11,1 11,1 11,2 11,2 11,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,1 1,1z
</StreamGeometry>
```

How can I create this path for any other customised icon?

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/cc188956.aspx